# Making a confirmation field that isn't part of the entity/class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a form that includes a field I wanted the user to enter twice to confirm there weren't any typos in it (like is often done with passwords).  The class backing the form includes this in the declaration:

```cs
[Display(Name = "Citation Number")]
[StringLength(20)]
[Required]
public string CitationNum { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[Display(Name = "Confirm Citation Number")]
[Compare(nameof(CitationNum), ErrorMessage = "Data entered does not match.")]
public string ConfirmCitationNum { get; set; }
```

This works great when using the data in the forms, I have the validation I want and the `[NotMapped]` DataAnnotation makes it so that field's data doesn't need to reside in the database.

Now, however, I'm trying to manipulate the data outside of a form and it threw up an Entity Validation error because my retrieved list of entities didn't have anything for that field when I tried to save it.  I realize I can just set that property in the entities before saving it, but it made me think that there is probably a better way to do this.

Is there a better way to make a validation field on a form and handle updates to the data as an entity, or do I just have to manually set that unmapped property to the one it is supposed to match each time I want to manipulate a set of records?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of several reasons to avoid passing entities to views. These are different concerns needing work-arounds for getting EF to ignore the data, but yet satisfy behaviour needs for the views. A view model should be used for views where the CitationNum and confirmation are projected from the Entity's CitationNum for existing data.

```
public class SomeEntity
{
   [Key]
   public int SomeEntityId { get; set; }
   public string CitationNum { get; set; }
   // ...
}

[Serializable]
public class SomeEntityViewModel
{
   public int SomeEntityId { get; internal set; }

   [Display(Name = "Citation Number")]
   [StringLength(20)]
   [Required]
   public string CitationNum { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Confirm Citation Number")]
   [Compare(nameof(CitationNum), ErrorMessage = "Data entered does not match.")]
   public string ConfirmCitationNum { get; set; }
}
```

then when prepping your data for the view:

```
var viewModel = context.SomeEntities.Where(x => x.SomeEntityId == someEntityId)
    .Select(x => new SomeEntityViewModel
    {
       SomeEntityId = x.SomeEntityId,
       CitationNum = x.CitationNum,
       ConfirmCitationNum = x.CitationNum,
       // ...
    }).Single();
```

Leveraging Automapper that can be done with a single `ProjectTo` call.